# Google cloud endpoints generate Java api HTTP 400 error

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-endpoints

Hey im trying  to develop a rest API  by using this doc  [go-endpoints](http://godoc.org/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/go-endpoints/endpoints)

I can test my app locally and on the app engine .

But i cant create a Java client in order to consume it on android device,
for some reason I'm getting an

> HTTP 400  No JSON object could be decoded

on this command

```
  GO_SDK/endpointscfg.py gen_client_lib java MY_FILE_NAME
```

This is the full stack trace

```
    mik@mik-Aspire-S3:~/go-programs/src/cloudEndPoints/app$ $HOME/go_appengine/endpointscfg.py gen_client_lib java ballota_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mik/go_appengine/endpointscfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/mik/go_appengine/endpointscfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/home/mik/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 561, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mik/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 557, in main
    args.callback(args)
  File "/home/mik/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 458, in _GenClientLibCallback
    args.build_system)
  File "/home/mik/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 335, in _GenClientLib
    build_system, client_name)
  File "/home/mik/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 366, in _GenClientLibFromContents
    raise ServerRequestException(error)
__main__.ServerRequestException: HTTP 400 (Bad Request) error when communicating with URL: https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/generate.  Details: ill-formed JSON: No JSON object could be decoded
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to built this sample project  [tictactoe](https://go-endpoints.appspot.com/tictactoe) as a Java client and i got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an issue in 
[crhym3](https://github.com/crhym3/go-tictactoe/issues/5) cloud endpoints example and he helped my to understand my error.

My mistake  was that i  tried to create the  client with the wrong URL address .

This is the wrong address.

https://winged-precept-894.appspot.com  this will return 404

And this is the correct  discovery api URL.

https://winged-precept-894.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/myapp/v1/rpc

So  it was a url error and not a Json oriented error .